# How to add listener for when chrome extension is first installed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that takes over the new tab page. I would like to show something to the user when they first install the plugin and open a new tab. I am trying to use

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details){
    console.log('test');
    alert('test');
});
```

from https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled to get this to work. However, after I install the plugin and open a new tab, nothing happens. Any advice?

Comment: Where are you putting that code? I believe it needs to be in a background script. See - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages

Comment: @levi yes, that works now! However, now I'm running into an issue in that the alert fires as soon as the extension is installed. Rather, I want it to fire when a new tab is launched for the first time after the extension is installed. Any advice on that?

Comment: In this case you dont even need a background script. Use `chrome.storage` to set whether the message has been shown yet. In the newtab page, check if message has been shown, if not, show message, and set it as shown.

Comment: See - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: Seems the question has been solved in the comments, please consider eleborate it as an answer, thx.

Answer (score 0):

For mv3, place the following in your background:

```
const installListener = (details) => {
  if (details.reason === chrome.runtime.OnInstalledReason.INSTALL) {
    // do something
  }

  if (details.reason === chrome.runtime.OnInstalledReason.UPDATE) {
    // TODO: show changelog
  }
};
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(installListener);
```